# Java - printing all ArrayList elements as a single String

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, tostring

My program prints out a library.  Each library is composed of books.  Each book is composed of a title and the authors of that book.  I have a driver program, a Library class, and a Book class.  My issue is that when I use my driver program that uses my `toString()` methods in the library and book classes to print the library, the authors of each book are appearing as `[author, ;, author, ;, author]` and I want them to print as `author; author; author`.

**Expected output: http://prntscr.com/810ik2**

**My output: http://prntscr.com/810ipp**

**My input: http://prntscr.com/810j6f**

**`getAuthors` is the method in my driver program that separates the authors (In the input file that the authors are taken from authors are separated by '*' instead of separated by ';' which is what i need in my output)**

Please let me know in the comments if there is too little info, too much info, if what I've given is too confusing, or if I didn't explain anything properly.  I'm new to Java and fairly new at posting questions here so please go easy on me.  Thank you!

Edit: Just in case here are my three classes (only the important stuff):

**Book.java:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Book implements Comparable<Book>
{

   private final String myTitle;
   private final ArrayList<String> myAuthors;

   public Book(final String theTitle, final ArrayList<String> theAuthors)
   {
      if (theTitle == "" || theAuthors.isEmpty() ||
          theTitle == null || theAuthors.get(0) == null)
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
         "The book must have a valid title AND author.");
      }
      else
      {
         myTitle = theTitle;
         myAuthors = new ArrayList<String>();
         for (int i = 0; i < theAuthors.size(); i++)
         {
            myAuthors.add(theAuthors.get(i));
         }
      }
   }

   public String toString() 
   { 
      String result = "\"" + myTitle + "\" by ";

      for (int i = 0; i < myAuthors.size(); i++)
      {
         result += (String)myAuthors.get(i);
      }
      return result;

   }
}
```

**Library.java:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Library
{

   public Library(final ArrayList<Book> theOther)
   {
      if (theOther == null)
      {
         throw new NullPointerException();
      }
      else
      {
         myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
         for (int i = 0; i < theOther.size(); i++)
         {
            myBooks.add(theOther.get(i));
         }
      }
   }

   public ArrayList<Book> findTitles(final String theTitle)
   {
      ArrayList<Book> titleList = new ArrayList<Book>();
      for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++)
      {
         if (myBooks.get(i).getTitle().equals(theTitle))
         {
            titleList.add(myBooks.get(i));
         }
      }
      return titleList;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String result = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++)
      {

         String tempTitle = myBooks.get(i).getTitle();
         ArrayList<String> tempAuthors = myBooks.get(i).getAuthors();
         Book tempBook = new Book(tempTitle, tempAuthors);
         result += (tempBook + "\n");
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

**LibraryDriver.java:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LibraryDriver
{
   public static void main(String[] theArgs)
   {
      Scanner inputFile = null;
      PrintStream outputFile = null;
      ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
      ArrayList<Book> books2 = new ArrayList<Book>();

      String[] filesInputs = new String[]{"LibraryIn1.txt", "LibraryIn2.txt"};

      try 
      { 
         outputFile = new PrintStream(new File("LibraryOut.txt")); 
         for (String fileInput : filesInputs) 
         { 
            inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileInput)); 
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) 
            { 
               String title = ""; 
               String input = inputFile.nextLine(); 
               //Read title 
               title = input; 
               input = inputFile.nextLine(); 
               authors = getAuthors(input); 

               //Insert title & authors into a book 
               Book tempBook = new Book(title, authors); 
               //Add this book to the ArrayList<Book> of books 
               books.add(tempBook); 

            } 
            Library myLib = new Library(books);
            outputFile.println(myLib);
            inputFile.close(); 
            myLib.sort();
            outputFile.println(myLib);
         } 
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      { 
         System.out.println("Difficulties opening the file! " + e); 
         System.exit(1); 
      }
      inputFile.close();
      outputFile.close();
   }
   public static ArrayList<String> getAuthors(String theAuthors)
   {
      int lastAsteriskIndex = 0;
      ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < theAuthors.length(); i++)
      {
         if (theAuthors.charAt(i) == '*')
         {
            if (lastAsteriskIndex > 0)
            {
               authorList.add(";");
               authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(lastAsteriskIndex + 1, i));
            }
            else
            {
               authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(0, i));
            }
            lastAsteriskIndex = i;
         }
      }
      if (lastAsteriskIndex == 0)
      {
         authorList.add(theAuthors);
      }
      return authorList;
   } 
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't add *any* commas or semi-colons... at the moment it looks like it would just print "Foo by author1author2". (As an aside, look into using StringBuilder instead of string concatenation in a loop.) This question is more complicated than it needs to be due to the introduction of libraries as well as books - if you're just trying to work out how to join a set of strings together, you could produce a short but *complete* program that did nothing but that, in less code than you've shown here. Instead we've got incomplete code which is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: toString() uses `,` by default. Create a string yourself and display it.

Comment: If all you want is to replace '*' with ';' - why don't you do `theAuthors.replaceAll("\\*", ";");` ?

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I was afraid someone would say that.  The issue is my program has gotten too complex for me to follow.  Even if I created a simple program for printing what I want, I'd have no idea how to print it in this program.  Would you be willing to go over it with me in a private chat so I can get an answer on this question?

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow works. If you aren't able to extract the relevant bits from your project, that's a skill you should be learning. One option is to create a copy of your project, and just start removing *all* code that isn't absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. Then you should at least have something *shorter* and complete. Often you will find that's enough to work out where the problem is.

Comment: I'd also ask you to consider why you're storing the authors of the book as a single string *anywhere*. Why go through all that parsing etc? Just have a collection everywhere you need a collection.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in a debugger, by the way? Currently I don't think you're really sure whether the problem is in the parsing or the formatting - and that's the very *first* thing you should work out.

Comment: All methods and ways of doing things in this project were required to be the way they are for the most part.  Sadly there's not much I can change right now.  All I need to do is figure out how to print the ArrayList elements as a single string.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added my full code so that people might better understand the question.

Comment: But without condensing it to just what's relevant? That's not helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet I must have misread, I'll try to do that, but I have to finish this in the next 40 minutes.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that's not Stack Overflow's problem. The intention is for this to be a site of good, clear questions that other people will find useful in the future. A question where a large portion of the code is irrelevant doesn't achieve that goal. (We still can't really run the code, as we don't have the input data.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I revised the code I added, is this more what you were looking for?

Comment: It's definitely better - but you've still got the bits before the complete code, and no sign of input or expected output. I still suspect the problem is with `getAuthors` instead of the formatting - have you tried changing your driver program to just use hard-coded data (constructing a list manually) rather than reading from a file? Then a) there would be less code; b) we wouldn't need a data file; c) it would make it clear that the problem is in the formatting instead (if it really is).

Comment: @JonSkeet Sadly I have to use an input/output system.  It's required for this project.  I'll take out more code and add expected output, my output, and my input.

Comment: You have to for the *project*, but not for this *question*. This is what I'm trying to get across to you - in order to solve your problem (and make this a good question) you should isolate the problem as far as possible. Have you worked out whether it's in parsing or formatting? If not, do so with a debugger. If you have, get rid of the other part of the code, for the sake of this question.

Comment: You code is incomplete and unrunable, where's the `getAuthors()` method from `Book`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Jon told me to only add code necessary for a general answer, if you'd like we can go in a discussion and I can give you my complete code.

Comment: @Trafton While I also agree with John, I can't see anywhere you call `public static ArrayList<String> getAuthors(String theAuthors)`, but I can see you calling `Book#getAuthor()` ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer in my Book class I have `public ArrayList<String> getAuthors(){return myAuthors;}` I also use it in my `add` method in Library class and I use it in my toString in the Library class.

Comment: @Trafton Based on my hobbled together example of your code and input, I get the expected output...Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're saying that my code was correct, but your printing method gave the correct output?  What did you do differently?

Comment: @Trafton I have no idea, I had to hobble some methods in

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah so you're saying there was no simple answer such as changing a toString method in one of the classes?

Comment: @Trafton You can have a look at the code I used below

Answer (score 0):

So, I hobbled together a runnable example of your code as best as I could and using

```
The Hobbit
Tolkien, J.R.R
Acer Dumpling
Doofus, Robert
```

As input, I get

```
"The Hobbit" by Tolkien, J.R.R
"Acer Dumpling" by Doofus, Robert
```

The code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibraryDriver {

    public static void main(String[] theArgs) {

//      ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(25);
//      books.add(
//                      new Book("Bananas in pajamas", 
//                                      new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B1", "B2"}))));
//      
//      Library lib = new Library(books);
//      System.out.println(lib.toString());
        Scanner inputFile = null;
        PrintStream outputFile = null;
        ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        ArrayList<Book> books2 = new ArrayList<Book>();

        String[] filesInputs = new String[]{"LibraryIn1.txt"}; //, "LibraryIn2.txt"};

        try {
            outputFile = new PrintStream(new File("LibraryOut.txt"));
            for (String fileInput : filesInputs) {
                inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileInput));
                while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                    String title = "";
                    String input = inputFile.nextLine();
                    //Read title 
                    title = input;
                    input = inputFile.nextLine();
                    authors = getAuthors(input);

                    //Insert title & authors into a book 
                    Book tempBook = new Book(title, authors);
                    //Add this book to the ArrayList<Book> of books 
                    books.add(tempBook);

                }
                Library myLib = new Library(books);
                outputFile.println(myLib);
                inputFile.close();
//              myLib.sort();
//              outputFile.println(myLib);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Difficulties opening the file! " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getAuthors(String theAuthors) {
        int lastAsteriskIndex = 0;
        ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < theAuthors.length(); i++) {
            if (theAuthors.charAt(i) == '*') {
                if (lastAsteriskIndex > 0) {
                    authorList.add(";");
                    authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(lastAsteriskIndex + 1, i));
                } else {
                    authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(0, i));
                }
                lastAsteriskIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (lastAsteriskIndex == 0) {
            authorList.add(theAuthors);
        }
        return authorList;
    }

    public static class Library {

        private ArrayList<Book> myBooks;

        public Library(final ArrayList<Book> theOther) {
            if (theOther == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            } else {
                myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
                for (int i = 0; i < theOther.size(); i++) {
                    myBooks.add(theOther.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Book> findTitles(final String theTitle) {
            ArrayList<Book> titleList = new ArrayList<Book>();
            for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
                if (myBooks.get(i).getTitle().equals(theTitle)) {
                    titleList.add(myBooks.get(i));
                }
            }
            return titleList;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {

                String tempTitle = myBooks.get(i).getTitle();
                Book b = myBooks.get(i);
                ArrayList<String> tempAuthors = b.getAuthors();
                Book tempBook = new Book(tempTitle, tempAuthors);
                result += (tempBook + "\n");
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class Book implements Comparable<Book> {

        private final String myTitle;
        private final ArrayList<String> myAuthors;

        public Book(final String theTitle, final ArrayList<String> theAuthors) {
            if (theTitle == "" || theAuthors.isEmpty()
                            || theTitle == null || theAuthors.get(0) == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "The book must have a valid title AND author.");
            } else {
                myTitle = theTitle;
                myAuthors = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < theAuthors.size(); i++) {
                    myAuthors.add(theAuthors.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            String result = "\"" + myTitle + "\" by ";

            for (int i = 0; i < myAuthors.size(); i++) {
                result += (String) myAuthors.get(i);
            }
            return result;

        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Book o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return myTitle;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getAuthors(String theAuthors) {
            int lastAsteriskIndex = 0;
            ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < theAuthors.length(); i++) {
                if (theAuthors.charAt(i) == '*') {
                    if (lastAsteriskIndex > 0) {
                        authorList.add(";");
                        authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(lastAsteriskIndex + 1, i));
                    } else {
                        authorList.add(theAuthors.substring(0, i));
                    }
                    lastAsteriskIndex = i;
                }
            }
            if (lastAsteriskIndex == 0) {
                authorList.add(theAuthors);
            }
            return authorList;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getAuthors() {
            return myAuthors;
        }
    }
}
```

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I copy pasted the code you gave word for word and still got my output.  It looks like I won't be able to finish the project perfect, what I have now will have to do.  Thanks for all your help though, the link you gave for runnable examples will help a lot in my future posts!

Comment: In that case I'm wondering if the input is the issue...Create a band new project, devoid of any of your other classes, nice and clean, copy the example code and input to it and run it and see what you get

Comment: I have to go to bed, I'll mull it over and as a professor on my campus and I'll get back to this discussion and let you know what I find out if you're interested.